# Is this an accurate translation?

Tags: translation

我同意这样的观点，但是这是否代表别的宗教人物也是一样的吗？

English:  I agree with your statement, however is it possible that they could have represented different famous religious figures?

I translated the English into lang-8, and a native corrected it this way.

Comment: From help center: "state which area you are having difficulty with. ... Open ended questions regarding the accuracy of a translation ... are not allowed."

Comment: 我同意你的观点,然而他们是否可能代表不同的知名宗教人物呢？

Comment: Did u translate the Chinese sentence into English, or Eng. into Chi.?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
我同意你的論點，但他們能夠代表其他不同宗教的知名人物嗎？

More colloquially,
我認同你說的，但你怎麼知道他們能代表所有不同宗教的人物？

I tweaked the wordings a bit, but the semantics should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Your translation seems incorrect.
I would translate it into:
I agree with your point of view, however is that mean other religious figures are the same?

Comment: I think you're reverse-translating a bad translation.